# is there a work-around to make rowspan work in MS browsers?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, html-table, microsoft-edge

I have a webpage at http://bikepaths.com/Armstead/GBA1.html , and I have set up an HTML table to arrange text and pictures using rowspan such that the first column has a small amount of text above a tall picture, while the second column has a tall picture above a small amount of text.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>George's first memory of note was ... </td>
        <td rowspan="2"><img src="image/IM-GBA1885.jpg" height="440" width="280"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2"><img src="image/IM-JBA4-GBA.jpg" height="400" width="280"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Also he recalled watching his half brother, James Benson Armstead IV <i>[on left]</i>, go through .... </td>
    </tr>
</table><br>
```

So 3 rows, with rowspan=2 on each of the picture cells.
This displays as desired in both Firefox and Chrome, but the MS browsers I have tried (IE11 and Edge) both display it as a simple 2-row table, leaving massive amounts of space above and below each text cell.

I know MS should be banned from creating browsers until they learn what 'following standards' means, but until that happens, is there a workaround to make this display properly in IE and Edge?

Comment: Could you post the HTML you are using?

Comment: I've added it to the question.

Comment: yes, there is a workaround. Stop using tables for page layout :)

Comment: "I know MS should be banned from creating browsers until they learn what 'following standards' means" By that logic, *everyone* should be banned from creating browsers because *everyone* violates the standards in some way, shape or form.

Comment: add a hidden first row that has 3 td elements.
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr> validator.w3.org/nu detects when columns or rows don't match the sum of row and col spans.

Comment: @RobParsons I tried your suggestion, a row with 3 blank <td> elements, and tried a row with 2 blank <td> elements - neither one had any effect on what I am seeing in the MS browser. I added <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr> immediately after the <table> statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<table style="table-layout:fixed">
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="3">three colunms width</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2">two columns width</td><td>one column</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="1">one column</td><td colspan="1">one column</td><td colspan="1">one column</td></tr>
</table>
```

note that the sum of the colspan attribute values or the sum of the number of td elements in each row equals the number of td elements established by the first (hidden, because the td cells are empty) row.

go to validator.w3.org/nu and copy and paste your markup into the direct input form and then press the validate button.... the w3 validators can detect where the number of td elements and the sum of colspan attributes does not match.

Comment: My issue was with rowspan, not colspan, but I tweaked your solution. With only two columns, I could NOT get the pictures to overlap (i.e, the top part of the column 1 picture to be in row 2 with the bottom part of the column 2 picture). However, when I added a third column with blanks in all three rows, I noticed a slight overlap. Thus, by making the second entry in that last column to be a series of <br>&nbsp; items, I could control the amount of overlap for the pictures in the second row. A little messy, but it works.